# WebKitLegacy - [_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] application crash in iOS10.0.1

Tags: uiwebview, crash, ios10

I am getting the following crash only in iOS10.0.1. Its not giving me enough stack trace information. The only clue I have is , seems to be happening from WebView.Because it says "WebKitLegacy  - [_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] ".

The crash log is given below. I have another crash group related to "updateSubviewsOfScrollContentViews" seems like all are related.

Any suggestions on this very helpful. Like how to debug this issue ? Where might be the problem?

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xcec18beb8
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: addObject:   


 Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x000000018d9fef30 objc_msgSend + 16
    1   UIKit                                0x000000019502abd8 updateSubviewsOfScrollContentViews + 184
    2   UIKit                                0x000000019502acdc updateSubviewsOfScrollContentViews + 444
    3   UIKit                                0x000000019502acdc updateSubviewsOfScrollContentViews + 444
    4   UIKit                                0x000000019502acdc updateSubviewsOfScrollContentViews + 444
    5   UIKit                                0x000000019502acdc updateSubviewsOfScrollContentViews + 444
    6   UIKit                                0x000000019502aad0 -[UIWebBrowserView _collectAdditionalSubviews] + 380
    7   UIKit                                0x000000019502a924 -[UIWebDocumentView _updateSubviewCaches] + 52
    8   UIKit                                0x000000019500d268 -[UIWebDocumentView webViewDidCommitCompositingLayerChanges:] + 44
    9   UIKit                                0x000000019500cf80 -[UIWebBrowserView webViewDidCommitCompositingLayerChanges:] + 80
    10  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018efba160 __invoking___ + 140
    11  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018eeadc3c -[NSInvocation invoke] + 280
    12  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018eeb26ec -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 56
    13  WebKitLegacy                         0x0000000194ae77f8 -[_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] + 152
    14  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018de3d200 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
    15  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018de3d1c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
    16  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018de41d6c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 996
    17  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018ef61f2c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
    18  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018ef5fb18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1656
    19  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018ee8e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 440
    20  GraphicsServices                     0x0000000190911198 GSEventRunModal + 176
    21  UIKit                                0x0000000194e67818 -[UIApplication _run] + 680
    22  UIKit                                0x0000000194e62550 UIApplicationMain + 204
    23  Essentials                           0x00000001000f5f08 main (main.m:52)
    24  ???                                  0x000000018de705b8 0x0 + 0enter code here
```

Comment: Which one do you use: `UIWebView`, `WKWebView`, or `SFSafariViewController`?

Comment: I am using WkWebView, I have the similar issue.